# non blocking php system call - tshark

Tags: php, system-calls

I am trying to start a tshark process capturing on the interface wlan0 for 5 minutes. As read in other threads I tried to direct output to a file like this:

```
$log = "sniff-".date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").".txt";
system("sudo tshark -i wlan0 -a duration:300 > /var/www/log".$log);
```

I was expecting the webserver to start the tshark process and move on. In the error log of the apache I can see the normal output of tshark:

```
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous
Capturing on wlan0
6 packets captured
```

What do I have to change for tshark to output into this log file and not interrupt the php script? Does a & suffice and if yes, where do I have to put it?

**Solution:**

```
system("sudo tshark -i wlan0 -a duration:300 > /var/www/log".$log." &");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the & at the end of the bash cmd it should disconnect it from the running session, but you could try using PHP threads or PHP fork to run the process off as a parallel process, providing your server has the relevant settings and modules installed to enable this.

```
system("sudo tshark -i wlan0 -a duration:300 &> /var/www/log".$log.' &');
```

Also, by adding &> as the redirect mode, it will redirect both STDOUT and STDERR streams to the log file. The messages you were seeing may have come through STDERR and may not otherwise appear in your log file.

Comment: I tried adding an ampersand as you said, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Well, it works now. Instead of adding an ampersand before and after the |, I just added an ampersand to the end and it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

as I interpret the log, the process did work and capture packets, despite the warning. 
But your process terminated when the php script finished. Try using

```
sudo nohup tshark -i wlan0 ...
```

Comment: Well, the problem is not that the tshark process is terminated, when the php script finished, but that the php script is blocked at the system call till the 300 seconds of tshark are over and tshark terminates itself.